# Rails setup; rails server command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to RoR and when I go try the rails server command I get this strange error message:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /Users/danielmiller/Desktop/railsTutorbook/myfirstapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: May I know your version of Ruby??

Comment: And don't forget `rake db:create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like the sqlite3 ruby gem is having some trouble.

first, make sure you have the libsqlite3 development package installed.

On a debian derivitive, this would look like

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

then, install the gem

```
gem install sqlite3
```

on a normal rails setup, bundler should be setup via Gemfile to install all the required gems for you.

```
bundle install
```

Comment: hey, I thought this would get me somewhere but even after successfully installing sqlite3 I still get the same error message  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Answer (score 0):

Install the gem sqlite in your application and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the rails . Are you having two different version of ruby?

please update latest Ruby-gems using

```
gem update
```

I would recommend you to reinstall the rails using the below command,

```
 gem install rails
```